# Retrieving something that could be null from a database

Tags: c#, mysql

My code is basicaly this:

```
//get connection 
//make connection string which returns one value
//open connection
string picture = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
//close connection
```

The possibility that the query returns null is there. So how can I find out if its null and then store it into my string? What I used above doesn't work because the string throws an exception. So can I temporarily store the value into something then toss it back out to the string? I don't want to run two ExecuteScalars to find out if its null first then store it.

Comment: Databases should *not* contain null values. Read up on table normalization.

Comment: Its not the the table contains a null value its that the relation does not exist.

Comment: @ChrisCooney: Why databases should not contain NULL values? NULL was designed to express "missing information and inapplicable information", it makes absolutely sense to use it where applicable.

Comment: @ChrisCooney Hes right man. It seems like using so many different tables for a relation that may add 1 null value to your table is terrible for queries. Its makes writing complex queries look like about 200 lines of code with no indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually do this:

```
string picture = null;
object picTemp = command.ExecuteScalar();
if (picTemp != null && picTemp != System.DBNull.Value) {
   picture = (string)picTemp;
}
```

`picTemp` will be `null` if no results were returned. It will be `System.DBNull.Value` if a result was returned but the value of the result is null.

Comment: Great thanks. I tried using object before but I forgot to remove .ToString() on my command -_-.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to check for `null`:

```
string picture = command.ExecuteScalar() as string;
if(picture == null)
{
    // Handle the NULL case
}

// Do something with picture...
```

As what I can see from the documentation, you don't have to check for `System.DBNull.Value` as it should not be returned by `ExecuteScalar()`.

> **Return Value**
>   Type: System.Object
>   The first column of the first row in
>   the result set, or a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) if the
>   result set is empty. Returns a maximum of 2033 characters.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx

Comment: I may be wrong on this because I'm going from memory, but "plain old `null`" is for queries that return no results. Example: `SELECT * FROM DUAL WHERE 1 = 2`. No rows, no columns; `ExecuteScalar` returns `null`. On the other hand, consider `SELECT NULL FROM DUAL`. This has a result set: one row, one column, and the column value is null. `ExecuteScalar` will return `System.DBNull.Value` here.